# how to filter out errors and exceptions of a particular type in smtp email appender used in logback.xml

Tags: xml, servlet-filters, logback, email, smtpappender

i am new to smtp email appender.i have a logback.xml file with the below shown content in the classpath of a project.
i have configured it like this

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
       <marker>ERROR</marker>
    </evaluator>
    <smtpHost>smtp.office365.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>***</smtpPort>
    <username>*****</username>
    <password>*******</password>
    <STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>

    <to>********</to>
    <to>*********</to> <!-- additional destinations are possible -->
    <from>******</from>
    <subject>TESTING ERRORS FROM WEB </subject>
    <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
      <bufferSize>1024</bufferSize>
     </cyclicBufferTracker>
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="emailappender" level="INFO"/>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="MAIN_FILE_APPENDER" />
    <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

the purpose of sending emails is satisfied but it is sending for all kinds of exceptions and errors encountered.
can we configure this in a way that we can send emails for only some kinds of errors and exceptions(like filtering on some basis).
Could anyone please help me with the xml code to be modified here.

Answer (score 1):

To control spam you can use the new Whisper appender as described [here](http://eclecticlogic.github.io/whisper/).

Statutory disclaimer: I'm the author of Whisper.